# Событие "Enabled" для button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть кнопка, хочу сделать так что бы она была неактивна с помощью события Enable, если в textbox нет символов либо есть только 0.При отсутствии символов в боксе, кнопка принимает значение false.
А при наличии каких-либо символов, кнопка возвращала обратно значение true. Сделал с помощью метода MouseMove. При наличии символов в боксе, кнопка имеет значение true, как и нужно, но когда она принимает значение false, значение true она уже не возвращает.

```
private void result_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == "0")
    {
        result.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        result.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как такое можно реализовать? И в чем вообще моя ошибка?

Comment: Ну чтоб true было нужно после мышкой пошевелить. Поскольку вы подписались на событие мыши. А правильно это ответ внизу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тебя интересует ивент твоего текстового поля TextChanged

```
private void TexBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    result.Enabled = textBox1.Text?.Length > 0 && textBox1.Text != "0";
}
```

Comment: Попробовал Вашу версию, у меня все равно при пустом textBox кнопка активна.

Comment: потому что этот ивент на запуске формы не отработал. Сделай по дефолту отключенной кнопкой кроме даного кода. Или вызови этот метод вручную на старте формы.

Comment: Еще при добавлении любого символа, кнопка неактивна. Хотя мне нужно наоборот, что бы неактивна была тогда, когда в боксе пусто. Попробовал оператор !=, все равно не помогло

Comment: какая-то странная логика. Ну поставь знак восклицания перед скобками. Или != в обоих условиях.

Comment: Пропустил ! после =, все работает, спасибо)

Comment: Свойство `Text` может быть еще `null`. Получается в итоге даже проще `result.Enabled = textBox1.Text?.Length > 0 && textBox1.Text != "0"`

Comment: `MouseEventArgs e` => `EventArgs e`

Comment: @aepot - свойству [Text](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,952c66876790b53a) задаётся пустая строка `""` при попытке задать `null`.